# Memory Vector Layer Corrupted?

Tags: qgis, vector, error, memory, qgis-2.4

I was working with a large data set that had data for roads, rivers, railways, etc. all together so I decided to break the different data out so I could label it differently on the map and check each on and off separately.  I selected all of one type, copied it to the clipboard, and pasted it as a new memory vector layer.  Everything was working fine yesterday, but when I opened the file this morning all of the data in the attribute table was gone in the vector memory layers I created.

I had toggled off edits and saved all my layers before closing yesterday.  Why did this happen? Should I have pasted as just a vector layer instead or should I have saved my selections as separate shapefiles instead?

Also, another issue I am experiencing is that I have several separate shapefiles with different address points.  I was copying and pasting points between shapefiles yesterday without issue (they are the same formatting in the attribute table btw) but when I tried to do that this morning I could paste, but not save the shapefiles.  I was getting the following error message:

> Errors: ERROR: 1 feature(s) not added.
>
> Provider errors:
>         OGR error creating feature -2: Attempt to write non-point (MULTIPOINT) geometry to point shapefile.

Why was this working yesterday and not today? Did I somehow change the type of shapefile (i.e point, line polygon) without realizing it?

I am using QGIS 2.4.0-Chugiak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question: *memory layers* are only stored by QGIS **temporarily**, so you should always save them as seperate shapefiles immediately if you don't want to lose any changes.

Secondly, I have never seen that error (I use QGIS 2.2) but some people claim it to be a bug which has been reported: https://hub.qgis.org/issues/10747

An alternative may be to create a new blank shapefile and paste all your required points that way?

Comment: Thank you Joseph - I didn't realize that memory layers were only stored temporarily. I may have to download and start using 2.2 so I can do my work until a fix comes out.  That thread you linked to was exactly what I am experiencing! Lastly, I did try creating a new blank shapefile and copying the points, however, same error occurred.

Comment: @user35127, your most welcome! Yes, there have been a number of issues regarding 2.4 which is why I'm sticking with 2.2 for the time being. Saying that, most issues do get resolved fairly quickly.

Comment: The issue mentioned above should be fixed now in latest qgis-dev. Give it a try, or wait for QGIS 2.6 to be released.

Comment: Thanks @AndreJoost, I am very much looking forward to using QGIS 2.6 for its new features.

Comment: To save the memory layers with the project there is a Memory Layer saver plugin. Very useful.